# dbaccess control output format regardless of result size

Tags: informix

Using Informix `dbaccess` e.g.

```
select col1, col2, col3 from MyTable
```

may output results like this

```
col1 col2                 col3
 100 The first row        blah blah
 101 The second row       more blah blah
```

or it may output results like this

```
col1 100
col2 The first row
col3 blah blah

col1 101
col2 The second row
col3 more blah blah
```

I need to make it choose one output format and stick with it so that I can parse it in a regular way.

Can I make it always output in either one style or the other?

I can use `unload to` and get a regular `a|b|c` format, which is nice, but

- I require the column names to be outputted
- I do not control the query, this has to work for an arbitrary SELECT, so I do not know the column names in advance

How can I force the output to be

1. always of a certain (any) fixed format
2. which includes the column names

?

Comment: That was one of the reasons I wrote my `sqlcmd` program many years ago.  You can find it at the [IIUG — International Informix Users Group](http://www.iiug.org/) web site in the [Software Repository](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL).  With it, you'd write `sqlcmd -d stores -H -e 'select col1, col2, col3 from MyTable` and you'd get one line with the column headings (`-H`) and the other lines in UNLOAD format.  You could add `-T` to get the column type information too, another line after the names (if requested).  Both the names and the types are in UNLOAD format.

Comment: You can also control the output format with `-F block` to get `column-name    value` format consistently, which emulates the DB-Access mode for when the columns don't fit across the page.  The default format is `-F select`, which prints the rows across the page without a delimiter after the last field (use `-F unload` to get a final delimiter().  Etc.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I might be able to use it, but how should I escape strings? https://pastebin.com/qaaPa8Dr My existing code uses `'a \'b c'` version

Comment: In which context?  Inside SQL, you should use `'a ''b c'` to get a single quote embedded into a string (double occurrence of a single quote to embed the single quote).  There's a moderate chance that the backslash-quote notation will also work.  I'd have to test that (and work out whether it is SQLCMD or the server that deals with the notation).  I often use `"He said, ""Don't!"""` and `'He said, "Don''t!"'` to show how to handle single-quoted or double-quoted strings containing either type of quote.

Comment: You'd use `'a"b''c\d'` IIRC: `UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn = 'a"b''c\d'` should do the job (even if DELIMIDENT is set in the environment).

Comment: Thanks, final question, I tried using `-D "\0"` to use the zero byte as a delimiter to avoid escapes in the output, but it didn't work, is that possible?

Comment: If it doesn't work, then the answer is "No", but it is a reasonable request.  Likewise with `-G '\0'` for null at end of record. _[…time passeth…]_  I can confirm that it doesn't work; it effectively requests 'no delimiter'.  I've got a couple of other changes that are needed; I'll try and get this fixed soon, maybe over the weekend.

Comment: Note that after `UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn = 'a"b''c\d'`, if you run `SELECT SomeColumn FROM SomeTable`, you'd see `a"b'c\\d` as the value from SQLCMD — the output format escapes single backslashes to double backslashes.  However, DB-Access generates `a"b'c\d` with a single backslash.  Ouch!